# Wordpress child theme white screen

Tags: wordpress

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I started out with an ordinary custom theme and then decided to extend the twentyfifteen theme instead so I brought in the parent theme's style [per the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and added the Template to my style.css file.

I had some custom stuff in functions.php, but even if I delete all of it except the wp_enque_style, I still get the white screen.

I have debug turned on. There aren't any errors at all. Just a white screen.

Here's my functions file:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

And my Style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: veochild
Theme URI: 
Template:  twentyfifteen
Author: veo
Author URI: 
Description: Veo Child Theme
Version: 1.0
License: 
License URI: 
Tags: 
Text Domain: veo
*/
```

Oddly enough, If I type in domain.local/wp-admin I am still able to access the admin site. If I change the theme to twentyfifteen it works fine. I don't have any other files in my theme directory other than functions.php and style.css and my theme folder is in the same directory as twentyfifteen.

Not really sure what else to look for.

Comment: you might have debug turned on but your php errors are more than likely turned off. This is a setting in php.ini.

Comment: @David - I do have display_errors set to on. I have had errors displayed before. This one seems a little different in that it doesn't display anything other than an empty head and body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, when I said:

> I don't have any other files in my theme directory other than functions.php and style.css

...I lied or I must have been blind. What was also in that folder was an empty `index.php` file.

It took me a while before realizing that. Thanks for anyone who looked at this. Sorry for the waste of time.